# Не могу продлить Apple Developer Program membership

Tags: мобильная-разработка

Кто сталкивался? нет кнопки продления, на форумах пишут отключить автопродление, но у меня нет такого пункта там где он у всех. Как в прошлом году продлевался не помню. Нашел видел на youtube - увидел куда ведет ссылка у кого есть кнопка - вставил свой ID в эту ссылку - не пашет. Поддержки у них на выходных нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте зайти через Crome, если не с него зашли - иногда в нем работает то, что в других нет и не показывается

Comment: спасибо. хро не помогал, а вот с мобильного телефона появилась кнопка. хотя в тот момент не мог открыть с компьютера - может это был временный глюк, потому как уже сказано выше я вручную делал ссылку, которая висит на кнопке и по ней не пускало